# Making Events using Threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, events, c++-cli

I have created a "Windows Form" and a second "Thread" .

- My form has a button that changes the value of a variable .
- My second thread uses an unstoppable loop to analyze that variable .

So this is an event that Changes the text of the form when the value of a that variable changes , but I cannot have my form or any of controls in the blocks of that "ThreadProcess" function because it is declared after that .

I also cannot declare my form before it because I need to use "ThreadClass" in form constructor . What should I do then ?

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System :: Threading;
using namespace System :: Windows :: Forms;

namespace Program
{
    static int Number = 0;

    ref class ThreadClass
    {
        public : void ThreadProcess ()
        {
            int SavedNumber = Number;
            while (1)
            {
                if(Number != SavedNumber)
                {
                    this -> Text = "Changed";
                    SavedNumber = Number;
                }
                else
                    this -> Text = "Nothing Yet";
            }
        }
    } ;

    ref class MainForm : Form
    {
        Button ^ ChangeButton;
        Thread ^ EventThread;
        ThreadClass ^ EventThreadClass;
        public : MainForm ()
        {
            EventThreadClass = gcnew ThreadClass ;
            EventThread = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ThreadStart ( EventThreadClass, & ThreadClass :: ThreadProcess ) ) ;
            EventThread -> IsBackground = true;
            ChangeButton = gcnew Button ();
            ChangeButton -> Click += gcnew EventHandler (this, & MainForm :: CloseButtonEventProcess);
            Controls -> Add (ChangeButton);
            EventThread -> Start ();
        }
        void CloseButtonEventProcess (Object ^ Sender , EventArgs ^ EA)
        {
            Number ++;
        }
    } ;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: avoid using `Abort()` on threads. If the thread is intended to stop running after the form is closed, then set the `IsBackground` property of the thread to `true`. A background thread stops automatically if the program closes: then you don't need to use `Abort()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip ProgramFOX .

Answer (score 4):

This is *very* inappropriate use for a thread.  Many problems with it, it is burning 100% core and not doing anything useful with all those cpu cycles.  Updating the Text property from a worker thread is just wrong and will buy you an InvalidOperationException, thrown by Winforms because updating properties on controls from a thread other than the one on which the control was created is illegal.

And worst of all, what you are doing just doesn't require a thread at all.  You only need a thread to do work that requires a long time, long enough to bog down the user interface.  More than a second or so.  Updating the Text property of a control takes a few *nanoseconds*.  You are at least 5 orders of magnitude away from needing a thread.

Use the TextBox' TextChanged or Leave event instead.

Comment: You are right I did not add InitializeComponent() . I added the code of InitializeComponent() to the constructor . This function is created by Visual Studio when you create a form using the designer . I don't use the designer and I code it myself .

Comment: And also how can I use a "TextBox" "TextChanged" event ? I want to see if a variable is changed , not the text of a "TextBox" .

Comment: The Text property of a TextBox is a variable as well.  Winforms tells you that it changed by firing the TextChanged event.  Writing your own code without help from the designer is fine, but you are not helping yourself writing correct code.  The designer makes adding an event handler for TextChanged very simple.  Do pick up a book about Winforms programming from your local bookstore or library to get ahead, right now you don't have the right "instincts" yet.

Comment: I actually want to make things myself and not to use things made by the others as much as I can . So , do you have any ideas how to make this thread more gentle to CPU ? I already know that I can use Form class instead of that thread class and I can declare thread process function in the form .

Comment: Every programmer has to right to write wrong code, it is an important part of the learning curve.  You just can't ask for help getting it wrong intentionally, that's not how this site works.  There's no way that anybody can reasonably help you recommending how to write threaded code with what you've provided.  It just doesn't make sense to use a thread.

Comment: I always thought events are the threads that check for changes and then run a block of code . If they are not then what are they ?

Comment: All the books just tell you to memorize a piece of code and use it whenever you need it . And also you said that I cannot make people to answer the questions in the wrong way , but I can ask for help to find the right way . Then why don't you help me with that and you simply say get a book ? I could think about it myself and not to waste my time here .

Comment: I did tell you how to do this correctly.  That you don't see that is not a problem I can help you with, you are clearly not interested in such kind of help.